# Two commands in one script ubuntu terminal

Tags: terminal, ubuntu-14.04, eof

I have two commands:

```
#!/bin/bash

python /srv/django/manage.py shell; execfile('/home/usr/myscript.py')
```

I want to use them in one script scr.sh. However as it is, I get errors.

> CommandError: Command doesn't accept any arguments
>   /home/usr/project.sh: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token
>   `'/home/usr/myscript.py''

where myscript.py is what the code I want running when the python shell appears. How could I go about achieving this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What was happening here is that ';' symbol will wait until something is performed/run in the shell. The correct syntax would be

```
#!/bin/bash

python /srv/django/manage.py shell <<EOF\ execfile('myscript.py') EOF
```

Comment: The here-doc should be on a new line, and the terminating EOF needs to be at the beginning of the line.